# Moving large static website with thousands of pages to WordPress, how to handle 301's?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am in a situation where I have a static website that has been in existence for over 8 years and has thousands of pages of content.

I need to move this site to WordPress and have found a plugin that does a great job of handling most of the legwork for me, but the question is how to handle all the redirects?

Correct me if I am wrong, but wont cluttering up an .htaccess file with thousands of redirects affect page load time?

Another caveat to this is that the domain name isn't changing, and there are thousands of horribly named .shtml files that will be re-named using WordPress Perma-links. The plug-in we're using to ingest the static pages into WP provides a list of redirects, but it just seems like there has to be a better way than adding thousands of lines to an .htaccess file to accomplish this.

So, my question is, what is the best practice for performing such a task, and, is there a programmatic way to handle it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would be helpful if you included the list of redirects provided by said plugin.

Comment: Thanks all. Essentially, I couldn't show the list of redirects due to contractual obligations but it would be safe to assume that the plugin created a list of redirects with the .shtml already stripped from the string.

Redirect 301 http://example.com/1324.shtml http://example.com/1324/

@cale_b you don't think thousands of redirects will affect page speed or site load time? Thanks again all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the names are matched - meaning that `www.example.com/my-page.shtml` is being made `www.example.com/my-page` - and this is 100% consistent - then you can create a redirect rule that just removes the .shtml: stackoverflow.com/a/11335332/870729:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.shtml
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.shtml$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also, IMO, using htaccess will be FAR faster / more efficient than using a php / programmatic method to redirect.  This style of redirect rule should have no noticeable impact on performance / load times.

Lastly, again IMO, it would be wise to make the "shtml" redirect first, let it sit (Google should pick it up in a few weeks, especially if you create a sitemap and submit to Google Webmaster Tools). *Then* you can begin the process of renaming the page(s) to more SEO-friendly / human-readable titles as it makes sense.